Running jupyter notebook in Pycharm2021 Professional has no response
I would like to run jupyter notebook in Pycharm2021 Professional Edition. I expect that when I run the cell, I will get the output correspondingly in the right window in Pycharm like the figure 1. However, the actual interface has no response no matter how many times I try.
I conducted the following installation procedures.

I input: pip install jupyter notebook in the Pycharm 'Terminal'. Note that my jupyter is the latest and the notebook is also the latest 7.2.1.
I input: jupyter notebook in the Pycharm 'Terminal' and it automatically redirects to the jupyter notebook on website. However, I find some doubtful points during the process. As shown in the figure 2.
figure 2: starting jupyter notebook via 'Terminal' in Pycharm.
First, although it allows me to input a password, actually it is unnecessary because when I click the 'Log in' button, it goes to the 'Home' page of jupyter notebook. Second, in the 'Terminal', I cannot see the token in the link. However, many articles on website show that the token should be included.
I test the jupyter notebook on website, which operates normally shown in the figure 3. You can see 'hello world' and 2 is the correct output.
figure 3: operating jupyter notebook normally on website.
It seems that my jupyter notebook itself is normal.
However, when I test the jupyter notebook in Pycharm, It has no response, no output, just the indication 'Starting Jupyter Server' shown in figure 4.
figure 4: No response when using jupyter notebook in Pycharm when I don't configure jupyter server.

I have tried the following steps.

Some articles tell me that I should configure jupyter server. I input the link in the figure. However, the Pycharm inform 'Jupyter Server URL is malformed'.
Then I remember that I don't have the token, So I input the link concatenate by '/?token='. After that, however, when I start 'Run Cell', It throws the error (Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'......) shown in the figure 5.
figure 5: Error when starting jupyter notebook in Pycharm when I do configure jupyter server.
Remember that in figure 4, if I don't configure the jupyter server with '/?token='. No error will be thrown. But also no output and response will feedback.
I also find that in the 'jupyter_notebook_config.py', there is such a saying,
"## DEPRECATED in 2.0. Use PasswordIdentityProvider.hashed_password #  Default: '' # c.ServerApp.password = ''". And in jupyter_server_config.json, there is also no password.

Note that due to stackoverflow principle, I cannot input the hyperlink, so I use the "'" character. The actual link doesn't have the "'" character.
